# Re-read configuration without restart

Tags: java, architecture, properties, configuration

Suppose I've got a Java application, which uses properties files as its configuration. Now I'd like to make the application *re-read* the configuration without restart. I'll call such configuration "refreshable".

What is the easiest way to do that?

Suppose I am developing an application from scratch. How should I design it to make its configuration "refreshable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) is probably the easiest way to go. Here is an [example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_events.html) of usage. There are many other features included, like hierarchical configuration (with overriding by defaults), JDBC sources, etc.

Comment: @Michael does this solves your problem, I thought APACHE framework only provides support to load various configuration files, but does this re-read the configuration as well without restart ..?

Comment: Here it is...  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html

Answer (score 1):

There must be some class say ConfigurationReader which has methods to read configurations and store them in-memory in some collection. Make sure that all the other classes uses the config information this in-memory map.

Now you can make a function call to re-read all the parameters and update the in-memory map, so that rest of the application will use the updated values from the map. This way you need to change code in entire application.